# Jquery autocomplete issue with word orders

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I use this code for create autocomplete

```
$( "#mainInputNameSearch" ).autocomplete({
    appendTo: $("#mainInputNameSearch").next(),
    source: leadNamesForAutocomplete,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#mainInputNameSearch').val(ui.item.label); 
    }
});
```

**leadNamesForAutocomplete** - array with data, structure for each element is {label:labelText, value: id}

It works, but have one issue. If i have element with label 'Fee Lea' and i enter 'Fee Lea' it works. But if i enter 'Lea Fee' system doesn't find this match.

How can i fix this? So if i enter 'Lea Fee' system will also get result 'Fee Lea'. So system will work with different words orders.
Thanks.

Comment: i use jquery-1.9.1

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an autocomplete library. Are you using jQueryUI?

Comment: yes, version is 1.12.1

Comment: i see above link with "answer", but really dont understand this(

Comment: @CrmProject: Basically the default search logic for the plugin is to check if the target string "contains" the entered text.  (Case insensitive of course.)  And the string "Fee Lea" certainly does not contain the text "Lea Fee".  The linked duplicate addresses the same concern.  The answer demonstrates that instead of using `leadNamesForAutocomplete` as your source, you can write a function for your source.  That function would be passed the information you need by the plugin, and in that function you'd perform your custom search logic on `leadNamesForAutocomplete` and use your results.

Comment: @CrmProject: There may exist other plugins or libraries somewhere that you can use for your search logic.  That would be outside the scope of the autocomplete plugin itself.